# HTML validation errors with data attributes

Tags: html, facebook, validation

I am getting a validation error from http://validator.w3.org as follows

1) Error Line 136, Column 34: there is no attribute "data-href"

2) Error Line 136, Column 259: there is no attribute "data-send"

3)  Line 136, Column 259: there is no attribute "data-send"

4) Line 136, Column 278: there is no attribute "data-layout"

5) Line 136, Column 304: there is no attribute "data-width"

6) Error Line 136, Column 326: there is no attribute "data-show-faces"

and my code is

```
<div class="fb-like"  data-href="{$url->job($details.jkey,$details.seocountry,$details.seocity,$details.seoindustry,$details.seojobtitle,$details.seoqulurl,$details.seojobSubCatagory)}" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Please help me to solve these bugs.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Here is not code writing service. You have to do your homework and start asking reasonable questions. You have 3 answers that are correct. If you have buggy code this is not our problem. We can help if you tried something to debug, but we will not write the code for you.

Answer (score 4):

I would guess that you are using the wrong [`doctype`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#the-doctype). Make sure your document starts with:

```
<!doctype html>
```

[`data-*` attributes](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes) are invalid unless you are using the HTML5 doctype.

Also, these look like HTML validation errors, not CSS.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
This is my doc type. Please chek my site http://eaussiejobs.com

Comment: @user1490780 - As I said in my answer, `data-*` attributes are invalid with that doctype. You will have to change it to `<!doctype html>`, or stop using `data-*` attributes.

Comment: But now it shows some error in my site as Warning: filemtime() [function.filemtime]: stat failed for /hermes/web09/b924/moo.freecostwebscom2/australia/jobs/themes/development/compile//%%F7^F7F^F7F34188%%header.tpl.php in /hermes/web09/b924/moo.freecostwebscom2/australia/jobs/core/plugins/Smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php on line 1390.  Please check my site http://eaussiejobs.com

Comment: Please check this page http://eaussiejobs.com/29878f4a/State_of_Queensland_jobs/Brisbane_jobs/Financial_and_Insurance_Services_jobs/Officer_jobs/_Graduates_jobs/Accounts_Payable_Officer_required_urgently_at_Davidson_Recruitment.html

Comment: @user1490780 - I'm not going to go through your entire codebase. Identify the cause of the issue, and ask a question on here about how to fix it.

Comment: I'm not going to go accept or use the answer because after implementing it , I got too many erros. If you are not able to look at the code better to go and sleep.

Comment: @user1490780 - Fair enough. My answer does answer your question in it's current form. It's not my problem that you have invalid markup. If you want constructive help, spend some time identifying the specific problems and then ask questions about them. I'm more than willing to look at relevant snippets of code, but not your entire site. I have plenty of other things to be doing.

Comment: Then please inform stackoverflow to remove the option to include site url in questions. With out seeing the patient how can a doctor prescribe medicine. ? Really bad man ...

Comment: @user1490780 - If you have questions or comments about how Stack Overflow works, you can ask on [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Why are you murmering man ? Now you have a lot of times to argue with me . You ahve no time to just chek the problem url , but you have more than 15 minute to argue with me . If you are not able to geive the answer , better to stop here and try any other simple questions to get some point . Bye

Answer (score 3):

Remove the data- attributes from your HTML. Then add the attributes using javascript before making the calls to facebook.

Here is an example with the use of jQuery:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div class="fb-like"></div>

var jQueryFBLike = $(".fb-like");
jQueryFBLike.attr("data-send", "false");
jQueryFBLike.attr("data-layout", "button_count");
jQueryFBLike.attr("data-width", "85");
jQueryFBLike.attr("data-show_faces", "false");

(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=&xfbml=1";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
```

Comment: One note only. +1 for the workaround for xhtml, but also js.src should have &amp; instead & else it produces validation errors

Answer (score 2):

Change your doctype.

sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>sample</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="fb-like"  data-href="{$url->job($details.jkey,$details.seocountry,$details.seocity,$details.seoindustry,$details.seojobtitle,$details.seoqulurl,$details.seojobSubCatagory)}" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="true"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time . But after implementing teh code Iam getting an error in my page as "Warning: filemtime() [function.filemtime]: stat failed for /hermes/web09/b924/moo.freecostwebscom2/australia/jobs/themes/development/compile//%%F7^F7F^F7F34188%%header.tpl.php in /hermes/web09/b924/moo.freecostwebscom2/australia/jobs/core/plugins/Smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php on line 1390". Now the css errors are solved.

Comment: Please see the  page : http://eaussiejobs.com/91e516cb/State_of_New_South_Wales_jobs/Sydney_jobs/Administrative_and_Support_Services_jobs/Managers_jobs/_Graduates_jobs/Business_Development_Manager_wanted_at_Apex_Resource_Solutions.html

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Your-Page" data-send="false" data-width="350" data-show-faces="false" data-font="arial"></div>
```

for XHTML Transitional replace with:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

//<![CDATA[

document.write('<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Your-Page" data-send="false" data-width="350" data-show-faces="false" data-font="arial"><\/div>');

//]]>

</script>
```

for HTML 4.01 Transitional don't forget escape </div> manualy, replace with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Your-Page" data-send="false" data-width="350" data-show-faces="false" data-font="arial"><\/div>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It also throws errors with short tags! After lots of googling, I have JavaScripts enclosed with `CDATA` for this to work with 4.01.

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">                (function(d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
         <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
             document.write('<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/virtualservicez" data-layout="button" data-action="recommend" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>');
             //]]>
        </script>
```

which worked for my website